# Regular Expression search in Autopsy

Tags: java, regex

I've recently been getting to grips with Autopsy, however when trying out the keyword search feature, I couldn't seem to get Autopsy to recognise contents of files that matched the regular expression. I simply made a document with phone numbers in (for example 01234 567890), and the regular expression built in for phone numbers didn't match it. So I tried to write my own as:

```
\d{5}\s\d{6}
```

Everywhere online tells me this is correct, yet it still doesn't find them. Further testing seemed to show that \s just would not pick up any whitespace in any file. Is this just a problem with Autopsy? Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell what result you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you want could be something like this:

`[0-9]{5}[ ][0-9]{6}`

I find that using Java format regular expressions in Autopsy is usually the simplest approach.

You can find full detail on the syntax for building expressions here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html